# trying to download video using Youtube-DL

Tags: youtube-dl

i'm trying to download a video from fox.com using youtube-dl
I was able to successfully do that the first time, but the second time i got this:

```
 HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

However it works for youtube videos and all other videos.
I'm not sure why it's not working anymore.

I did this:

```
youtube-dl --rm-cache-dir
```

still wont work

this is my command:

```
youtube-dl --no-check-certificate https://foxtv-vod.ercdn.net/Mucize-Doktor/fragmanlar/36/PRY1MUCIZED_EP36_05KSMPRS_V1.smil/hlssubplaylist-video_2400000-audio_126416.m3u8?e=1604159028&st=KjHdKui2__4cGA8u4OY-kA
```